# Positioning a drawable left of TextInputLayout

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout

I'm trying to achieve the effect like so: [image]

The suggested way to do this is to add a `drawableLeft` to the `EditText,` but the `EditText` underbar extends all the way below the drawable.

Another possible way is to create a `ImageView` to the left of the `TextInputLayout`. The problem with this is it becomes difficult to keep the icon exactly aligned with the `EditText` since the `TextInputLayout`'s error message toggles extra height, depending if it's visible. This would require calculating the `TextInputLayout`'s error message view height and placing a placeholder under the icon to toggle its visibility if the error message is visible or not.

Is there a good way to achieve this design with a `TextInputLayout`?

Answer (score 0):

This work for me, the trick is put it all into a LinearLayout with horizontal orientation.

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_user_login_dark"/>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
                android:id="@+id/username">

                <EditText

                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/hint_username"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
```